# Bluetooth mouse OKLICK 406S connects, but work as a battery level indicator, not mouse in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: mouse, indicator, bluetooth, battery

```
$ upower -d
Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_AC0
  native-path:          /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/ACPI0003:00/power_supply/AC0
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Fri Aug 16 02:32:44 2013 (315 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  line-power
    online:             yes

Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
  native-path:          /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0
  vendor:               A25
  model:                A15--22
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Fri Aug 16 02:32:49 2013 (310 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               fully-charged
    energy:              53.732 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         53.732 Wh
    energy-full-design:  60.2 Wh
    energy-rate:         0 W
    voltage:             16.676 V
    percentage:          100%
    capacity:            89.2558%
    technology:          lithium-ion

Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_hid_30o03o01o25o02o2f_battery
  native-path:          /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:22/0005:056E:0061.0004/power_supply/hid-30:03:01:25:02:2f-battery
  model:                Laser  BTmouse
  power supply:         no
  updated:              Fri Aug 16 02:37:49 2013 (10 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               discharging
    energy:              0 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         0 Wh
    energy-full-design:  0 Wh
    energy-rate:         0 W
    percentage:          100%
    capacity:            100%

Daemon:
  daemon-version:  0.9.20
  can-suspend:     yes
  can-hibernate:   no
  on-battery:      no
  on-low-battery:  no
  lid-is-closed:   no
  lid-is-present:  yes
  is-docked:       no
```

I have the battery indicator of my OKLICK Bluetooth mouse (model 406S) in place of my laptop battery indicator. And the mouse is not working as a pointing device...

Now I use another Bluetooth mouse - A4-Tech BT-630 -  without problems... and without additional forward/backward buttons :-)

**How can I correct this behaviour? How to see the laptop battery's status? How to use my mouse as a mouse (pointing device)?**

Answer (score 0):

It happens with every bluetooth mouse that informs its battery status. I got my mouse working again doing these steps: connects the bluetooth mouse, wait it to stop pointing, disable my laptop bluetooth adapter, re-enable it, switch to some tty (TTY1, for example) and switch back to TTY 7 (graphical interface). Doing so, my mouse battery stopped being monitored and the pointing service was well stablished again. Now I have no problems (until reboot system :-/ ).

Source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1072234/comments/2